# Inserting a list in python using a loop

Tags: python, arrays, list, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to make a python program that I can insert a recipe, and I want to make a list of the ingredients. I know how to insert data as a certain spot in the list, using .insert, but when I use a for loop, I keep getting an error that says "TypeError: insert expected 2 arguments, got 1." I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Please help.

```
print("")
ingred=[]
measure=[]
n=0
i=0
for n in range(0,n+1):
    ingred[n]=ingred.insert(input("What is the ingredient?(type done to end ingrediants)"))
    n=n+1
    measure[i]=measure.insert(input("How much of the ingredient?"))
    i=i+1
```

Comment: Use `append()` to add to the end of a loop.

Comment: Why are you putting the ingredients and measures in separate lists? Use a list of tuples or dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

Use the append function:

```py
print("")
ingred=[]
measure=[]
n=10
for n in range(0,n+1):
    ingred.append(input("What is the ingredient?(type done to end ingrediants)"))
    measure.append(input("How much of the ingredient?"))
```

I don't really understand your `n=n+1` code, so I removed it here - this should just run N times, which I set to be 10.

Answer (score 0):

The `insert()` function takes two arguments, the element to insert and the index to insert it. To insert a recipe at the end of a list, use `append()`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't add to a list by assigning to an index. You use the `append()` method.

And if you want to stop when they enter `end`, you need to assign the input to a variable so you can check it before appending to the list.

```
while True:
    name = input("What is the ingredient?(type done to end ingrediants)")
    if name == 'done':
        break
    ingred.append(name)
    measure.append(input("How much of the ingredient?"))
```